# empty JSON parameters for array POST in swagger

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, swagger, nestjs

I'm using nest.js and I have a post route to add new news to database
so I used postman to send array of objects like this:

```
[
{ 
    "newsTitle" : "title1",
    "newsDescription": "description1"
},
{ 
    "newsTitle" : "title2",
    "newsDescription": "description2"
}
]
```

and this the code for post in my controller:

```
@Post()
  async create(@Body() body: NewsDto[]) {

    const len = body.length;

    if (len == 1) {
    }

    else if (len > 1) {
    }

    return this.newsService.createNews(body);
  }
```

so everything work fine in post and saving data in database
but when I use swagger I get the Model of for the dto of this controller like this:

[image]

You can see that the the parameters of dto not displayed here and I get the "Array" title instead because I use `@Body() body: NewsDto[]` and it's array as you see

[image]

also here in the post I can't get the JSON so I can add it or post it in another word

so how to handle this so when the length of array only 1 object then I return NewsDto parameters and if the length of array more than 1 object so return the NewsDto parameters too instead of Array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add the `@ApiModelProperty()` decorator to your DTO's properties:

```
export class NewsDto {
  @ApiModelProperty()
  newsTitle: string;

  @ApiModelProperty()
  newsDescription: string;
}
```

Then add `@ApiImplicitBody()` to the controller method:

```
@Post()
@ApiImplicitBody({ name: 'news', type: [NewsDto]})
async create(@Body('news') body: NewsDto[]) {
```

Comment: I'm already add this! and for other post functions where I use dto not as array like now the swagger work fine and the parameters of dto displayed well @Kim Kern

Comment: For an array type, you also have to add `ApiImplicitBody` to the controller method, see my edit.

Comment: When using typescript, nestJs or swagger in controllers, you can use this as well;


@Post()
@ApiBody({ type: [objectItem] })
async create(@Body() body: objectItem[]) {